# How can i display google like my details when somebody search for my website?

Tags: seo

[image]

How can i display my company detail like google do?

Comment: you would be better off asking questions like this here: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply to Google Places for Businesses [here](https://www.google.com/business/placesforbusiness/).

Google can give your more information [here](https://support.google.com/places/answer/142906?hl=en). Sorry for the concise answer, but this should cover it!

Answer (score -1):

There are several reasons to appear there I believe. Google shows description depending on the popularity of the thing you are searching for.

Forexample:

Search for [Steve Jobs](https://www.google.com/#fp=5c04aeb196e4933b&psj=1&q=steve+jobs&qscrl=1):
You will see some images, short introduction, wikipedia page and so on.

Search for [Yahoo](https://www.google.com/#fp=5c04aeb196e4933b&psj=1&q=yahoo&qscrl=1):
You will see G+ follow button, short introduction, wikipedia page, stock price and so on.

Search for [Turkey](https://www.google.com/#fp=5c04aeb196e4933b&psj=1&q=Turkey&qscrl=1):
You will see flag, map, short introduction, wikipedia page, points of interest and so on.

So the point is being popular. If you have lots of images in google image database, if you have many followers on google+, if your blog is popular, if there is a wikipedia page for your name you will probably be there.